# Scalable background images that change on click

Tags: javascript, background

I have a question that's somewhat of an extension of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471809/change-pre-defined-body-background-image?answertab=active#tab-top).

I have my background images working; however, instead of having them tile automatically, I would like to link them to scale to the browser. I know how to create a scalable background image using CSS, but I don't know how to link said CSS to the backImage variable in the script (available below, or after the jump from the previous thread) so that it applies to all of the various images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var backImage = [
    "images/street.png",
    "images/market.jpg",
    "images/building.jpg",
    "images/skyscraper.jpg",
    "images/gasstation.jpg",
    "images/trees.jpg"
];

function changeBGImage(whichImage) {
    if (document.body){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backImage[whichImage]+')';
    }
};
</script>
```

The tricky part is I can't apply the class to the HTML because I'm already applying this...

```
<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(1)">Change</a>
```

...to an existing div in the HTML with multiple other classes; hence I need to add the class to backImage or the specific pngs and jpgs in the javascript.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend helped me solve my problem. Here goes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var backImage = [
    "images/vintagemap.png",
    "images/earbuds.jpg",
    "images/flames.jpg",
    "images/grass.jpg",
    "images/library.jpg",
    "images/shapes.jpg"
];

function changeBGImage(whichImage) {
    if (document.body){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backImage[whichImage]+')';
        document.body.className = 'bgchange';
    }
};

</script>
```

I added the line "document.body.className = 'bgchange';" below my original JS, then wrote the following CSS class:

```
.bgchange {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

It will now resize any photo to a scalable, full-screen background image.

Hopefully someone else finds this helpful!

Comment: Congrats on the fix, Paige!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: Yep, thanks! I had to wait 24 hours before I could accept my own answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

as part of your `changeBGImage()` function, you could make additional `.style.` changes to `document.body` to do whatever you like to each background image as it changes.

EDIT:

Essentially, take this:

```
function changeBGImage(whichImage) {
    if (document.body){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backImage[whichImage]+')';
    }
};
```

And turn it into this:

```
function changeBGImage(whichImage) {
    if (document.body){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backImage[whichImage]+')';
        document.body.style.backgroundSize = '###px';
    }
};
```

Or, if you want to set some CSS other than `background-size` on the body element, you would do that after the `.style.` parameter instead. Just remember, when translating CSS to JS, hyphens are removed and the next letter is capitalized (just like `background-image` in CSS becomes `backgroundImage` in JS)

Comment: I just don't know the proper js structure and how to apply to that to my existing code. Could you write out an example, please?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Unfortunately, I'm still not explaining myself very well. Here goes: I have a class with a number of different CSS attributes. How can I apply that specific class to this script so that it applies to each of the background images when displayed? (Again, thank you!)

Comment: Hmm... does the CSS change based on the image? If not, why not just apply the CSS, instead of to a class, directly to the `<body>` tag? Or put the class you've defined on the `<body>` tag in the markup? If you want to do it in the JS, it would be `document.body.setAttribute("class", "className");`

Comment: The CSS doesn't change based on the image. Each of the images simply stretches or shrinks automatically to fill the browser window. I can't assign the CSS to the body because I already have an existing body background-image (a repeating .png) which remains in place until the other images are triggered by clicking on certain links. I'll try the JS you listed, though, and let you know how it goes. Thanks so much!

Comment: Okay, the following did not work: 

function changeBGImage(whichImage) {
    if (document.body){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backImage[whichImage]+')';
 document.body.style.backgroundImage.setAttribute(".bgchange");
    }
};

I placed "document.body.style.backgroundImage.setAttribute(".bgchange")" before the "document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backImage[whichImage+')';" then after (as seen above). Placing it before simply broke the images; placing it after didn't do anything. Using "document.body.setAttribute("class")" will apply to the body, not the images.

Comment: you have `document.body.style.backgroundImage.setAttribute(".className");` ... try this instead: `document.body.setAttribute("class", "bgchange");` ... you cannot apply a class to an attribute ("background-image"), only to an element (like "body")...